# HTML links in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to place a hyper link in my javascript code (asda) in expample <<<

this is my code:

```
var klachtinternet = confirm("Heeft u een klacht over ons product Internet?");
    if(klachtinternet == true){

        document.writeln("<fieldset>" + 
            "<legend>" + " Internet" + "</legend>"  
            + "Klant meldt probleem met Internet" + "<br/>" + "<br/> " );

            var nu = confirm("Kunt u browsen naar www.nu.nl?");
                if(nu == true){

                    document.writeln("Browsen nar www.nu.nl lukt"  + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
                              }
                                else{
                                    document.writeln("Probleem : Browsen naar www.nu.nl lukt niet" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" //I WANT HERE MY HYPERLINK TO ANYTHING. I TRIED LINK() I TRIED A HREF NOTHING WORKED!);
                                    }


                                var refresh = confirm("Reageert de pagina snel na het indrukken van F5?");

                                    if(refresh == true){

                                        document.writeln("De pagina laadt snel" + "<br/>" + "<br/>");

                                                        }

                                                        else{
                                                            document.writeln("Probleem : De pagina laadt niet snel" + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
                                                            }
                                                        if(nu == true){
                                                            document.writeln("...U kunt browsen naar www.nu.nl ");
                                                                      }
                                                        else{
                                                            document.writeln("...U kunt niet browsen naar www.nu.nl ");
                                                            }
                                                        if(refresh == true){
                                                            document.writeln(" maar de pagina laadt snel.");

                                                                            }
                                                        else{
                                                            document.writeln(" maar de pagina laadt niet snel." + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
                                                            }
                                                        if(nu == true){
                                                            document.writeln("<Ul>" + "<li>" + "Browsen naar www.nu.nl lukt" + "</li>");
                                                                       }
                                                        else{
                                                            document.writeln("<ul>" + "<li>" + "Browsen naar www.nu.nl lukt niet" + "</li>" + "<br/>");
                                                            }
                                                        if(refresh == true){
                                                            document.writeln("<li>" + "De pagina laadt snel" + "</li>" + "</fieldset>");
                                                                            }
                                                        else{
                                                            document.writeln("<li>" + "De pagina laadt niet snel" + "</li>" + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + "</fieldset>");
                                                            }
                                                            };
```

How to add the hyperlink where i marked it?

Comment: `document.writeln("Probleem : Browsen naar www.nu.nl lukt niet" + "<br/>" + "<br/> <a href='some/url'>Link</a>" );` ?

Comment: What is "asda"? Also, could you please reformat your code so it doesn't go way off to the right?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this.

```
<a href="http://www.yourlink.com">Visit Link</a>

document.writeln("<a href='http://www.yourlink.com'>Visit Link</a>");
```

Comment: Please use comments to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @Filburt Sorry, I recently got the 50 reputation. I was not able to comment the last time.

Answer (score 0):

document.writeln("http://www.google.com'>Google");
Just do like this.